# Is it possible to use InboxStyle and BigText both in same notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I created a notification with

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle
```

and add text by using

```
inboxStyle.addLine
```

for multiple text messages. But, I when I added

```
Notification.BigTextStyle
```

in notification, `BigTextStyle` not working because of notification already `setStyle`.

My notification is;

```
Notification summaryNotification = new
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
                    .setContentTitle("title")
                    .setStyle(addInboxStyle())
                    .setStyle(addBigTextStyle())
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setChannelId(notificationChannelId)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it is not possible
but you can get similar behaviour using MessagingStyle notification, you can use big messages without expanding and with expanding the notification and also you can have multilines in a notification

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MessagingStyle

```
NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message message1 =
        new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(messages[0].getText(),
                                                      messages[0].getTime(),
                                                      messages[0].getSender());
NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message message2 =
        new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(messages[1].getText(),
                                                      messages[1].getTime(),
                                                      messages[1].getSender());

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_message)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(resources.getString(R.string.reply_name))
                .addMessage(message1)
                .addMessage(message2))
        .build();
```